# Animating a Spinning Wheel click at each section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a spinning wheel animation at

https://codepen.io/dpegasusm/pen/jrBKNk

The wheel center is supposed to click as each of the different sections of the wheel pass by it. currently it does not. Anyone have any ideas what i can do to fix it so that each time the color change passes the arrow it correctly ticks?

it needs something to slow the ticking animation down with the speed of the wheel as it eases.

Here is the Javascript:

```
//set default degree (360*5)
var degree = 1800;
//number of clicks = 0
var clicks = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){

/*WHEEL SPIN FUNCTION*/
$('#spin').click(function(){

    //add 1 every click
    clicks ++;

    /*multiply the degree by number of clicks generate random number between 1 - 360, then add to the new degree*/
    var newDegree = degree*clicks;
    var extraDegree = Math.floor(Math.random() * (360 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    totalDegree = newDegree+extraDegree;

    $('#inner-wheel').css({
        'transform' : 'rotate(' + totalDegree + 'deg)'
    });

    $('#center').addClass('click');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#center').removeClass('click');
    }, 6000);

});

});//DOCUMENT READY
```

And the CSS for the clicks:

```
@keyframes tick {
   0%, 100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }

  50%{
    transform: rotate(7deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
  }
}

.click {
    /* -webkit-animation: tick 0.2s ease-out infinite; Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-name: tick;
    animation-duration: 0.2s; /* or: Xms */
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Comment: do you notice that it "ticks" many times after the wheel stops spinning? This should be a clue as to where you are going wrong

Comment: CSS `transform: 'rotate()'` creates the animation, so there's no loop that will line up in JavaScript. I would rotate by 18 degrees and multiples of that, to increase and decrease speed, based on 20 parts to your 360.